# Data annotations modelbinder in new mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, modelbinders

Hi we are trying to upgrade our project to work in the latest version of VS 2010 and i have encountered a problem with the old Data Annotations Modelbinder.

Dim modelBinder = New DataAnnotationsModelBinder()

modelBinder.InvalidValueFormatter = _
  Function(propDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor, value As String, displayName As String) _
                String.Format("'{0}' är ej ett korrekt värde för {1}.", value, displayName)

```
        ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = modelBinder
```

What Im trying to do is to overide the default errormessage for wrong datainput ("The value '{0}' is not valid for the {1} field.)

I try to get the default modelbinder to assign it a new errormessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post about this problem which solved my problem:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1512140/3606268.aspx#3606268

Comment: then you should mark this answer as "correct" to avoid confusion.